# Explanation needed for the representation of simplex as a polyhedron

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polyhedra, simplex

In convex optimization book (by Stephen Boyd) it is mentioned that the simplex for $k+1$ points $v_0,\cdots v_k$ is defined as $$S=\{\theta_0v_0+\cdots\theta_kx_k| \theta_i\geq0, \sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\theta_i=1\}.$$ To show that they assume that the points are affinely independent. Based on this they form a matrix $B$ such that $$B=[v_1-v_0\quad v_2-v_0 \cdots v_k-v_0]$$ In the book author say that $B$(whose rows are $n$ and columns are $k$) has rank $k$. Does it means that for a certain dimensional space with $n$ dimensions the simplex can be defined for only $k+1\leq n$ number of points?

Comment: In a space of $n$ dimensions, one cannot fit in a simplex of dimension $>n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you for your comment. Does this means that simplex is only defined on a space if the number of points that are considered are smaller than or equal to the dimension of the space?

Comment: No. For example a triangle is two-dimensional but has three vertices.

Comment: @Hobbyist so $k=3$ and $n=2$ right. We know that the rank of a matrix with $n$ rows and $k$ columns cannot be greater than $\min(n,k)$ which is $n$ in this case. So why in the book they say that the rank of matrix is $k$?

Comment: @FrankMoses This is because they define the simplex as a facet of the cross-polytope (hyper-octaheder); therefore they embed it within one dimension plus. In fact, S contains an equation within the set definition!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of simplex assumes $\{v_0,...,v_k\}$ are affinely independent. That says that $k+1 \leq n$ since we cannot have more than $n$ independent elements in $\mathbb{R}^n$.